# ¿hay alguna forma en que javascript identifique si el objeto html es un select o un input?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy desarrollando una herramienta en una página web que tiene varios formularios para el llenado de información, mi consulta es si es posible con javascript  diferenciar entre un select o un input.

Les agradezco la ayuda

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que "identifique"? ¿Qué quieres hacer con ello? Con js se podría ver lo que es pero si no sabemos para qué o en qué contexto es difícil mostrarte un ejemplo

Comment: creo que le falta contexto a esta pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, todos los elementos tienen su nombre guardado en el atributo `tagName`

```js
let c1=document.getElementById('campo1');
let c2=document.getElementById('campo2');

console.log('es un',c1.tagName)
console.log('es un',c2.tagName)
```

```html
<input id="campo1"/>
<select id="campo2"><option value="valor">Algo</option>
```